# Sklearn not working no matter what i do (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling sklearn.

I always get this error,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [12], line 2
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 from sklearn.tree import DesicionTreeClasifier
      4 music_data = pd.read_csv('music.csv')
      5 x = music_data.drop(columns=['genre'])

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

I have tried what i just said,

Comment: its possible you've installed it for a different python version

Comment: how do i check it

Comment: how did you install sklearn and how are you running your program? from console or are you using an IDE like Pycharm?

Comment: i installed it through pip and i am using it in vscode and jupyter

Answer (score 0):

I have faced that problem a lot and solved by installing that library instead of
sklearn.

```
!pip install scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be an issue with the module installation, but...
You mispelled 'DecisionTreeClassifier' into 'DesicionTreeClasifier'